# PHP file_get_contents doesn't work with www.skelbikas.lt

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I faced with a problem when I use the file_get_contents() function.

It works fine and pass the result from amazon.com search for example: file_get_contents ("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=java+coding&x=0&y=0");

But I need to get result (save as string) from file_get_contents ("http://www.skelbikas.lt/paieska.php?kat=83&zodis=iphone&nuo=0"); - when I trying this, it pass as string the index page of skelbikas.lt.

Where is the problem?

Thanks for quick response.

Using the cURL lib the situation is the same - with amazon.com works fine - I got the result in example_homepage.txt, I tried to write skelbikas.lt index page - it works fine too, but http://www.skelbikas.lt/paieska.php?kat=83&zodis=taisymas&nuo=0 doesn't - write nothing (null) to a file. :?

Comment: Edit the default php user agent to a one similar to internet explorer user agent for exampel

Answer (score 0):

try to use CURL

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.skelbikas.lt/paieska.php?kat=83&zodis=iphone&nuo=0");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```